# Curiosity with caterpillars?

Tags: curiosity

Why doesn't curiosity (or other) use caterpillar tracks (like tanks) instead of wheels?
It would be good for rough terrain and slow speed, and this is exactly the situation.

Regards

Comment: Welcome to [space.se]! Unfortunately, this question was already asked and answered in [Wheels vs. tracks for rovers](http://space.stackexchange.com/q/668/49) thread, but I thought you might also be interested in two similar threads on [robotics.se], namely [Wheels vs Continuous Tracks (Tank Treads)](http://robotics.stackexchange.com/q/541/1822) and Why do [Mars rovers designers prefer wheels over tracks?](http://robotics.stackexchange.com/q/558/1822). Similar questions can also be searched for, through tags [tag:rovers], [tag:movement] and [tag:curiosity]. Thanks!

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't think others had this same question.

Comment: No worries, you're new to the site, you'll learn your way around. It's just not constructive to have nearly identical questions posted multiple times on the same site, that's all. ;)